# Calculate effect of drag on ball in motion

Tags: applied-mechanics, mathematics, drag

So I’ve been trying to work out the range of a ball that has been projected by two spinning discs please when accounting for drag-

This is what I got so far:
$V=V\cos\theta$, $T=2V\sin\theta/g$ , and $Range=V*T,$ thus,
$Range= v^2\sin(2\theta)/g,$ but this doesn’t account for drag?

Where do I go from here please and is the above even correct please?

Comment: I don't think your equations are right, even for the zero drag case.

Answer (score 0):

when there is air resistance the horizontal component of velocity is not constant anymore and it decays.

Let's set the origin at the launch point with the X, Z axes, and C as positive constant friction or drag of the air.
The equation of motion:

$$
m\,\frac{d{\bf v}}{dt} = m\,{\bf g} - c\,{\bf v},$$

$$
V = ( V_X, V_Z) \quad g=(0,-g),v_t =terminla \ velocity=mg/c$$

$$ \frac{dv_x}{dt}=  - g\,\frac{v_x}{v_t},$$

$$ \frac{d v_z}{dt}= - g\left(1+\frac{v_z}{v_t}\right).$$

Integrating X component

$$
\int_{v_{x\,0}}^v\frac{dv_x}{v_x} = - \frac{g}{v_t}\,t,
 $$

Wher $ v_{x\,0} = v_0\,\cos\theta$
is the $x$-component of the launch velocity. therefore

$$\ln\left( \frac{V_X}{V_{X_0}}\right)= \frac{-g}{V_t}t, \ then $$

$$V_x=v_0cos\theta*e^{-gt/v_t} $$.

The x component will decay exponentially.

Applying the vertical forces and integrating we get:

$$V_Z=V_0sin\theta*e^{-gt/V_t}-V_t* \left(1-e^{-gt/V_T} \right)$$

Among other things, the above implies that if the ball stays in the air much longer than the order of $,V_t/g \ $it will fall vertically.
I know this answer can use some details and graphs, I come back and finish them.

Comment: Would the surface of the ball have an effect? golf ball cf tennis ball cf cricket ball or similar?

Comment: @SolarMike, yes, the surface of the ball would change the drag. Some machines shoot with a pitch, which would affect drag too.

Comment: drag is proportional to v^2.

Answer (score 0):

Aero drag is proportional to v^2, which means there is no algebraic solution. So you either approximate, by linearising it over the range of speed of interest (this would get ugly quick), or use a numerical solution (which is what is usually done).